# Style pdf page without knowing its number in weasyprint

Tags: css, pdf, pdf-generation, weasyprint

I'm creating PDF from HTML using [weasyprint](https://weasyprint.org/). I have a content that has dynamic number of pages.

I can start a new page after it with `style="page-break-before: always;"`.
How do I make this new page yellow?

I would use `@page :nth(3) { background: yellow; }` if I new it was third page. But I don't know the length of the content before.

Maybe something like `<page>` could be styled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found in [samples](https://weasyprint.org/samples/)! You can use `page` css property to name target page.

```
@page mypagename{
 background: yellow;
}

#element-on-styled-page{
 page: mypagename;
}
```